# calculate total value with condition

Tags: python, pandas, analytics

I am a newbie with pandas and numpy. I have a question regarding to calculate total value with a condition from a different columns

Since I have over one million tickets for my project, I use this function to return the value
`data[data['FinalBatteryTestDecision'] == 'GOOD BATTERY'].sum()['ToolType']`

However, the code takes forever to return the value. I wonder are there any methods to calculate the sum? I am looking forward to hearing from all

Comment: Use `data.loc[data['FinalBatteryTestDecision'] == 'GOOD BATTERY', 'ToolType'].sum()`. The problem with your current approach is that you are summing **EVERY** column. I bet you have some string columns, and summing 1 million strings into one enormous string with the addition operation is going to take a very very very long time. That small modification only sums the ToolType column, which is hopefully numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs a small fix. You can use the following code instead.

```
data[data['FinalBatteryTestDecision'] == 'GOOD BATTERY']['ToolType'].sum()
```

Comment: check comments, there is better solution like this.